# Trouble Understanding Definition: Expected Value

Tags: probability

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding the definition below, in which the full text can be found at: https://github.com/mtomassoli/papers/blob/master/inftheory.pdf

**Definition 3.** If $X$ is a random variable and $f$ a function, then $Z=f(X)$ is a random variable such that, for all $z$,

$$\begin{align}
p(z)&=~P(Z=z)\\&=~P(f(X) =z)\\&=~P(X \in f^{-1}(z)) \\&=~\sum_{x:f(x)=z}p(x)
\end{align}$$
I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind the last two bits $f^{-1}(z)) =\sum_{x:f(x)=z}p(x)$, including what the notation $x:f(x)=z$ means. Thanks y'all :-)

Comment: $\sum_{x:f(x)=z}$ refers to summing over all values $x$ such that $f(x)=z$. (Presumably, you are working with discrete random variables so that the range is countable).

Comment: In addition to what @LoveTooNap29 said, note that you've misread the parentheses. The thing that equals that summation is not $f^{-1}(z))$ but $P(X\in f^{-1}(z))$.

Comment: Ok thanks, still not sure why it's $(∈−1())$ here, sorry, really new to this :-)

Comment: $f(X)=z$ if and only if $X\in f^{-1}(z)$ where $f^{-1}(z)$ is the *inverse image* of $z$ i.e. the set $f^{-1}(z):=\{x:f(x)=z\}$.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up the comments:

1. $\sum_{x: f(x)=z}$ refers to summing over all values $x$ such that $f(x)=z$ (and presumably, you are working with discrete random variables so that the range is countable).
2. It is not $f^{-1}(z)$ but $P(X\in f^{-1}(z))$ that is equal to the following sum (but this may have been a typo...).
3. $f(X)=z$ if and only if $X\in f^{-1}(z)$, where $f^{-1}(z)$ is the *inverse image* of $z$, i.e. the set $f^{-1}(z):=\{y:f(y)=z\}$.